# How to integrate searchable Activity with Ok Google voice search?

Tags: android, search

I am trying to implement the [Ok Google Voice Search integration](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html). However, I am unable to deeplink into my app when I say "Search for Android on app_name." Instead, it simply searches the term on the web.

Here's what I did:

1. Create /res/xml/searchable.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:hint="@string/search_hint">
   </searchable>
   ```
2. Create a new Activity

   ```
   public class ExposedSearchActivity extends Activity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           String search = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
           Log.wtf("", "q=" + search);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Attach intent filters to the searchable activity

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".search.ExposedSearchActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
       android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
       <!--Deeplink from google now-->
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       </intent-filter>
       <!--Making it searchable-->
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.app.searchable"
           android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
   </activity>
   ```
4. My test device is a Nexus 5 running Lollipop LPX13D with Google Search 4.0.26.1499465.arm

What other steps might I have forgotten? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @1, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I tried both methods with no avail. T___T

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent Is your app published in the Play Store? It needs to be before the feature will work.

Comment: @4, Indeed! That was the missing link. Looks like we can only test via adb commands for now.

Comment: I enjoyed the Log.wtf() very helpful :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After lots of searching, I have found the answer in a [comment on Google+ by the author of the blog post, Jarek Wilkiewicz](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/afSRdDQiy1N).

> Yes, **the app must be published to the Play Store** in order for the
>   feature to work. One way to help debug your end is to trigger the
>   intent via adb, for example: adb shell am start -a
>   com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query foo

So I tested this feature on an app that is already in the Play Store, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you. This has been driving me nuts for the best part of a day

Comment: Any hacks to make it work? Has anyone found anything on this?

Comment: @2 you must implement the code in an app that is already published in the Play Store. Simply redo the steps I listed in my question in a published app and voice search should work.

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent, my app is published on playstore but i am installing from adb and its not working. Do i need to download from playstore to make it work ?

Comment: No, you can make it work with debug builds installed via ADB.

Comment: The google plus link is not working now. Any other links where I can look up the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have found working solution for this google voice search commands for our Android Application.

Refer below links to make it works:

1) https://gist.github.com/raveeshbhalla/186325d1bb25d13bd7a0

2) https://github.com/google/search-samples/issues/24

3) https://antonioleiva.com/voice_search_google_now/

4) https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/

5) https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#java

As the above answer listed by *Some Noob Student*. i am going further for 
**how to test it with debug apk with adding String in search query?**

Open command prompt in your PC then change path to your adb path. then execute below commands.

Note: before executing below commands close your debug app then test.

1) adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query app_package_name

2)adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query "Hello" app_package_name

Comment: You don't need first adb command. the second is enough to open android application and execute the code.