# Unable to implement Google API 'Search using a specific app'

Tags: android, google-api

I am trying to implement the '**Search using a specific app**' functionality as per the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Search). But I am unable to get it working. This is my query '**Ok google, search for xyz on helloapp**'

Following is my implementation. I have added meta data which is not required, but did not work without it either.

**Implementation**

**Manifest**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />

    </activity>
```

**Searchable Activity**

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchlayout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(SearchIntents.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())){
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I just read in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982653/how-to-integrate-searchable-activity-with-ok-google-voice-search that the app needs to be published to app store for the functionality to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982653/how-to-integrate-searchable-activity-with-ok-google-voice-search), that the app has to be published first for the functionality to work. However, we can emulate this with the following adb shell command

```
adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query 'search for xyz on..' packagename
```

Comment: Just to add it seems it also has to be publicly available for it to work.