# What does Google Now use to determine the App to search with?

Tags: android, google-voice-actions

[The Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#SearchOnApp).

I need to have my App called on searches in the style:

> search for cat videos on youtube

How does Google Now determine which App should be called? Obviously, it takes `youtube` in the example case, but how is that used?

The reason for my question, is that the App that I am working on does not get called when I provide a character for character correct search on the Apps name. The Apps name has 3 words, would that be an issue? Is there a way that I can provide multiple strings for Google Now to react upon to ensure my App gets a chance to fire.

When I issue this test command, the App is called perfectly:

> adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION
>   --es query "Bang" com.package.name

An example command I would give might be:

> search for Bang on TV Search Engine

Comment: App needs to be in store: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982653/how-to-integrate-searchable-activity-with-ok-google-voice-search

Comment: Yes. That would be the issue. Thank you.