# ok google, voice actions, search through app data

Tags: android, android-intent, google-voice-actions

every one.
I faced to a bit strange problem. My goal is to handle ok Google search query and open an app with this query.
Needed queries:
  Call buddy (opens my application's activity with that contact info and propose to make a call with voip)
  Search buddy on "app Name" (should open my application's activity and display in a list all occurencies)

I'm already tried these approaches:
1. I've created an activity with intent-filter with handle

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

But every time i try to "Call buddy" standart call application oppens.

2. I've created an activity with intent-filter handle using google.gms.actions approach

   ```
   <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   </intent-filter>
   ```

but still no luck. 
i can create a search query on with

```
adb shell am start -a "com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" --es query "[query keyword]" -n "com.testapp/.MainActivity"
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer you will first need to publish your app on the store before it will work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26983470/811749