# Android Voice Interaction

Tags: android, voice, google-now, voice-interaction

I have referred [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/voice-interaction/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) for providing voice interaction in my app.
I followed the same step but still not able to open my app using voice command for example: Find pizza in my app.

As I am not able to open the App by voice command isVoiceInteraction() is always false.

Please help if anybody has successfully implemented voice interaction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982653/how-to-integrate-searchable-activity-with-ok-google-voice-search