# Voice Search is not working from ok google

Tags: android, google-now, google-voice-search, searchactivity

I have integrated voice search from ok google using below.
AndroidManifest Entry :

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ExposedSearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

in ExposedSearchActivity - onCreate()

```
  if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)) {
        String search = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Log.wtf("", "q=" + search);
 }
```

**I have published the app in closed alpha on playstore. Still Activity is not getting opened from ok google.**
I have tried voice command like 'ok google search for salad in MyApp' or 'search for salad in MyApp'.

Although from adb it is getting opened by command as below .

```
adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION  -e query "salad" com.abc.MyAppp
```

Its been 2 days when i published my app but still from google assistant or ok google voice search is not opening MyApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question for future reference.
I have copied above code from and published my app in alpha release.
[How to integrate searchable Activity with Ok Google voice search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982653/how-to-integrate-searchable-activity-with-ok-google-voice-search)

Just remove below intent filter from the manifest and it is working for me.

```
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
```